# Pandas not reading all tables from website due to a "show more" tab on website

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

so this website im trying to scrub data from

nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/coronavirus-us-cases.html

is only printing the first 9 states due to a "show more" tab hiding more tables.

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/coronavirus-us-cases.html")
print(Tables[0])
```

Is there any way to have it print out the hidden tables? I was thinking along the lines of using selenium to click on the "show more" option for me but was unsure that would be an efficient way or not

Comment: use selenium or similar

Comment: Try using Selenium, rate its efficiency for you, then add the results to your question. Then we can help you further.